# Import Data from S3 To Dynamo using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

If I have a 1GB file in JSON format on S3. I would need a lambda function that has more than 1GB memory to load all of the file at once?

I would like to transform it with lambda, then put it into a dynamodb table.

The json format for many of the files are :

```
[
 {
   //data
 },{
   // Data again
 }
]
```

So it's an array of data items, that will be loaded with Golang. Another option would be to split up the big file into 100MB files for example, I would have about 100 files as there are many 1GB files. Not sure of the best solution to go right now, this would only happen once as an initial migration.

Comment: Will the entire JSON file end up as a single DynamoDB record? Or will each entry in the array inside the JSON file be a separate DynamoDB record, or something like that? Note: "The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB, which includes both attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the size limit."

Comment: @MarkB Yeah each entry will correspond to a row insertion or deletion.

Comment: OK so you need to use some sort of streaming JSON reader to read a few entries from the file, issue a batch insert to DynamoDB, free up memory, and then read some more entries from the file... I'm not familiar with JSON readers in Golang so I can't provide specific code, but I've done this sort of thing before in other languages.

Comment: @MarkB Alright, thanks. What do you mean by free up memory? Can I not just provision a 3GB lambda file and read the massive JSON file in?

Comment: Yeah I guess the Lambda limits have been increased and you have up to 3GB memory in the execution environment now. So you could read the entire thing in. I thought that was the issue you were asking the question about though. If you already knew you could read the entire file into memory, what is the problem you need help with?

Comment: @MarkB I was not sure what the right way to do it was, or if the lambda may time out mid process

Comment: Well the Lambda may definitely time out mid process, it depends entirely on how long your function takes to process such a large file. Why are you doing this with Lambda anyway? Are you wanting to trigger the process whenever a file is uploaded to S3?

Comment: I was going to setup a cron job with a lambda function to process small bits of data, and so decided to use lambda for the initial migration too. I was not sure of any other way to import it into dynamoDB easily.

Comment: What makes Lambda easier than just running your migration script on an EC2 instance? It seems like Lambda adds some variables, like process timeouts, that actually make it more difficult.

Comment: @MarkB With lambda I just write a couple functions in Golang and deploy. EC2 scripts are foreign to me. The timeout limit is 5minutes, I think it would depend on how long it takes to transfer from s3 also.

Comment: Running it on EC2 would be no different than just running a script on your local computer, except it would have faster access to S3 and DynamoDB.

Comment: This may be a better solution. I will look up how to run EC2 instances with S3 and dynamoDB.

Comment: Another solution to import data into DynamoDB is to use an AWS Data Pipeline, you can find more info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html